# When using the CoordinatorLayout my ScrollView has an incorrect size

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, android-scrollview, android-design-library

I'm using a ScrollView in a layout, and am attempting to use the new [`CoordinatorLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) from the [design support library](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html).

My layout file looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      ...
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ... />
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When testing this the scrollview only occupies part of the screen. What went wrong?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The standard ScrollView is only meant to be used as a parent. You need to change the ScrollView to a [`android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

An example can be seen in the reference documentation for [`AppBarLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html).

Answer (score 6):

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as
>   both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions
>   of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

You can use a NestedScrollView within a parent ScrollView. NestedScrollView is used when there is a need for a scrolling view inside another scrolling view. This is where it is useful, when the system needs to decide which view to scroll.

Here is an example of NestedScrollView with CoordinatorLayout:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

         <!-- Your scrolling content -->

     </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="match_parent">

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

         <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                 ...
                 app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```