# SearchView inside Coordinator layout

Tags: android, layout, android-coordinatorlayout

How can i achieve following layout design where on scrolling up i just get the view with searchview :

1 ----

[image]

2------On Scrolling up :

[image]

I've tried putting views at certain places in the layout but searchview always ends up in the top most area instead of below home logo or not even visible.

My current layout without any searchview is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#CFD8DC"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.svatts.my22.ScrollingActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"

                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try [NestedScrollView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30574304/6005977)

Comment: can u elaborate a bit more , i am already using nestedscrollview in content_scrolling which does the purpose of having `app:layout_behavior=@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behaviour`

Answer (score 1):

Change your entire toolbar into the following and mind this line:

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"



<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">
```

Then under your toolbar add your view with tabMode scrollable like this:

```
<your.search.layout
        android:id="@+id/your_search_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="your_height"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
```

And add following layout to your content_scrolling you want to scroll with the tab bar

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Working Example

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Comment: I just tried this , the editText that i used as search view , is coming on the very top (just under the status bar) , and on scrolling up it disappears.

Comment: Added a working example. With following gradle build versions:
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

Comment: i'll post an answer with working code of mine , the issue got resolved when i changed the height of CollapsingToolbarLayout from match_parent to any value , and simply added an edittext below toolbar then .

Answer (score 0):

You can use **NestedScrollView** for this purpose along with **AppBarLayout**. For better compatibility use *EditText* instead of *SearchView*.

More information [here](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/06/android-tip-searchview-below.html).